# Are there any super villains in "The Boys"?

Tags: the-boys, the-boys-2019

(I am only 3 episodes into The Boys, nor have I read the comics, so I don't know if this is answered later on).

---

In *The Boys* (2019 TV series) it seems that the world has an immense number of superheroes, even to the point that Vought desires to have a Supe in basically every small town/city across the US.  In the actual crime fighting situations we have seen to date the Supes are only taking down normal human criminals.

So given the wide extent of whatever mutation turns a human into a Supe, why are there apparently no super villains in this universe?

This is especially odd given that:

> A lot of the Supes we have encountered so far are immoral/unethical - attributes of your typical super villain. (So perhaps you could argue that they are their own super villains?!)

And as an explicit Supe example

> A-Train's FWB, Popclaw is so down on her luck (after being a well recognized Supe in the past) that she can't even pay the rent on her apartment, and is also basically a junkie (and dealer to A-Train).  So it wouldn't be much of a step for her to turn criminal.

Note that by super villain I mean doing things that super villains generally do - holding entire cities to ransom, stealing super weapons etc and not the normal human crimes of theft, bank robbery and murder etc.

Comment: Just to be explicit do you want answers that cover both the comics _and_ TV series?

Comment: You could argue that many of the Seven fit that description...

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Both TV and comics would be fine, but preferentially for the TV series.  However I would assume that the overall universe is basically the same in both cases (but I may be wrong about that)

Comment: @eshier I agree that most of the 7 are not of the best character (and I covered that), but it's a big leap from being a crime fighter to being openly criminal.

Comment: @eshier It's already ugly but you say it gets *more* ugly?!?!? lol.

Comment: Related: [Do they have Supervillain(s)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/102792/49)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes, in the shows they show up

There are super villains later on and their existence is a major plot point. It is revealed in later episodes that

> A-Train has been running Compound V to various terrorist organizations, who have been using the drug to try and create supervillains. All this is done by Homelander in an attempt to make it impossible for the US government to deny supers in the military, now that 'the enemy' has their own super terrorists, who could easily commit mass-murder and genocide.

Comment: I'd say that's sort of in the Iran-Contra realm of political type actions rather than a Batman/Superman super villain etc

Comment: Given that the show is totally up-ending what a super hero/villain is I can see that I need to totally change *my* perceptions!

Comment: [This transcript site](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/episode_scripts.php?tv-show=the-boys-2019) only has 2 instances of "villain", both referring to the new enhanced humans, so it's not dealt with much in the show.  We also learn that Vought somewhat orchestrates captures that the "heroes" do & apparently control Compound V (to some extent) so any villains may be on the payroll, too.

Comment: @eshier Is an "enhanced human" the same as a "supe villain"?  Supes seem to be a genetic mutation rather than a jacked up human

Comment: @Theik A simple "you're wrong about that" would have sufficed :D